# What is the origin of "rock" meaning "utilize"?

Tags: slang

Urban Dictionary example:

> "you can have the bed, I'll rock the couch"

Earliest example I can think of:

> RUN D.M.C. "It's Tricky" -- "It's tricky to rock a rhyme . . . "

Now it seems pervasive.  Is there something else that put it on the map or did it just take 25+ years to slowly filter into the mainstream from Ebonics (unlike, e.g., "Word Up," which seems to have risen and fallen over the same period).

Answer (score 9):

Firstly, while I see what you're getting at, I don't think *rock* is a synonym for *create* or *utilize* in the phrase *rock a rhyme* or *rock the bells*. I think a more appropriate synonym is *excel at* or *rule*. I think this sense is also what we mean by "rocking the couch." — That couch is mine, I'm totally have the best sleep of my life on that couch, you have the bed, no problem!

This is the same sense as *you rock!* Yes, I ROCK THAT COUCH. OK, I'm being a bit facetious here, but you see why those two examples cited here as "origins" don't connect exactly with the *rock the couch* meaning.

It's hard to pin down when this sense of *rock* became to mean what you're trying to express, because there is no hard line separating that sense from the older sense. *To rock* has meant *to dance/create music/party/excel* for a long time. When can the "new" sense be completely extracted from the "old" usage, as the word gradually becomes used in nearly every situation? *(qv. "nice")*

Ultimately, this meaning of *rock* has its origins in the phrase *rock and roll*, coming from a euphemistic verb phrase common among Black speakers of english meaning "to have sex". (Move back and forth.) This hidden meaning appeared in song titles and dance styles since the early 1930s. Which gives, of course, a whole new meaning to the phrase *I rock the couch.*

I found this quote in an article about Scotty Morris in the [August 1988 issue of SPIN](http://books.google.com/books/about/SPIN.html?id=XAZuVTiu8yMC):

> A neighborhood basketball star, he called himself La Rock because the player who scored the most points in a game was said to have rocked it, rocked the party.

Comment: Interesting.  I agree that a prominent current usage is very close to "I will [facetiously] excel as a wearer of this red sweater!" (which is what most white Americans my age -- late 30's would mean by it) whereas for younger folks I think the irony has slowly faded into self-esteemed contentment about legitimately "rocking" every outfit every day.

Comment: p.s.  on the basketball quote in particular, that's tricky because a basketball, unlike other balls, is a "rock."  I well remember the day that one of the few black members of my high school tennis team admonished one of the white players for calling tennis balls "rocks"!  (He suggested that they could at most be called "stones".)

Comment: +1 - One could argue that "rock" has been used in this sense since the '50's when the term first came into common use in association with music (and quite likely as a euphemism for sex).

Comment: Yeah, but I still think there's evolution over time . . . 20 years ago you either rocked your driver's ed test or you didn't . . . 60 years ago "rocking around the clock" was a special occasion, etc.  Today . . . baby you're a firework!  My adoptive 12 year old sister "rocks" most every quotidian fashion/life choice she makes  . . .

Comment: Put another way, "I'm going to rock Driver's Ed" can now simply mean, "I'm going to take Driver's Ed [instead of English]"

Comment: @Del I agree, but my contention is that it's hard to pin down exactly when "rock" started to take on the broad and more watered down meaning you speak of. *Rock* is undergoing the same process *nice* did in the 19th century, when the meaning of *nice* changed from "agreeable, delightful" to "kind, thoughtful" until Fowler pronounced in 1926 that it was "too great a favorite with the ladies, who have charmed out of it all its individuality and converted it into a mere diffuser of vague and mild agreeableness."

Comment: Hadn't heard that about "nice" -- the shift in meaning to "kind/thoughtful" resembles Nietzsche's point about how "good" went from the opposite of "bad" (as in low quality) to the opposite of "evil" . . .

Comment: @Del - I have to say I have never heard it used to mean "do something but not necessarily in a particularly unusual way", like you seem to think it now means. I don't know whether to flat out disagree with you, or just assume you hang out in different linguistic circles than I do. I've perhaps heard it used **sarcastically** that way...

Comment: I'm mainly basing things on my 12 y.o. sister but if you scroll through urban dictionary a bit there's a great one four pages in (but still positively rated) re how it now means ANY verb or adj., e.g., "Dude, can you ROCK me $20?"

Comment: @Del - lol. I guess that would make it the "urban" equivalent of the word "smurf" among the Smurfs.

Answer (score 1):

There is an earlier example, also from 80's rap which I am pretty sure got the ball rolling and introduced a new definition of the word into the mainstream.

LL Cool J came out with "[Rock the Bells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_the_Bells_%28song%29)" in 1985, the third single from his debut album *Radio* in 1985, two years before Run D.M.C. released *Raising Hell*, off which "[It's Tricky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_Trickye)" was the third single.

Comment: I don't think this can be a definitive answer. *Rock the bells* could be quite literal in that song in the sense of *making noise/music with* or *shaking violently* which has been a meaning of *rock* for quite a while longer.

Comment: Thanks, good stuff! Interesting in that whereas the meaning of "word up" didn't change much as it quickly went mainstream it seems like there's been a long slow progression from rock in the context of "create (non-rock) music" to "Should I rock the red sweater or the blue one"? (Not that color choice was insignificant to 80's rappers!)

Comment: @ghoppe - Agreed. This isn't so different from 1983's Rock You Like a Hurricane from the Scorpions, or even 1955's Rock Around the Clock. The term was always a double-entendre, so by definition it had non-musical meanings.

Answer (score 1):

The term "Rock & roll" doesn't come from movements during a dance. It comes from a drug reference meaning to use cocaine (rock) & then to "roll" a joint (pot). Musicians were considered to be on the inside track when drug knowledge & use was concerned. Therefor the term " You rock" is a positive affirmation originating from quality cocaine which forms rocks when it is processed.

Comment: This is a comment on another answer.  It doesn't address the current use of *rock* as *utilise*.

Answer (score 0):

This usage of the work 'rock' has quite a history behind it.

The original use of the work 'rock' (in this sense) came from 'rock and roll'.

At this point, he phrase 'rock and roll' had a very physical, even sexual meaning.  It refereed to the way that people moved while listening to the music.

Over time, the term 'rock' evolved to mean the ability for a musician (or anyone else) to inspire the 'rock and roll' feeling in someone.

- Those Guys Rock!

As the term became part of every day informal slang, it started to be used to refer to a job done well.  I was often used to replace another verb.

- You really rocked the potato salad.

After years of over use, the term simply became a cool way to reefer to doing anything, especially if the activity was not very attractive.  In this case, the word 'rock' was used to impart a scene of acceptance, attractiveness or confidence.  It's intended to raise spirits and improve moral by attaching a bit of the 'rock and roll' feeling to something unrelated.

- I'm going to rock these chores!